# How to fix this error "Error: You are calling withStyles(styles)(Component) with an undefined component."

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I try to make a react date range picker with Material UI. First I had some problems with makeStyles and I resolve it with withStyles : import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

Now I have this problem : "Error: You are calling withStyles(styles)(Component) with an undefined component."

[image]

Here is the structure of my code :

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
const useStyles = withStyles((theme) => ({
     ...
)}

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
     ...
  );
}

export default App;
```

and my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.10.11",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.39",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^4.0.0-alpha.12",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "form-data": "^2.5.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.9",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
    "react-use-uuid": "^1.1.0",
    "react-uuid": "^1.0.2",
    "recharts": "^2.0.9"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

`withStyles` doesn't do the same thing as `makeStyles`. You appear to have just changed the name of the function you're calling, but you're still treating it as though it will make a custom hook. `withStyles` is a higher order component: you give it a component, and it will return a new component wrapped around yours. It then passes the classes in to your component as a prop.

If you want to use `withStyles`, it will need to look like this:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

function App({ classes }) {
  return (
     ...
  );
}

export default withStyles((theme) => ({
     ...
)})(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

By the docs - https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api - you suppose to use `withStyles` like so -

`export default withStyles(stylesObject)(component);`